# Curse status in direwolf20

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-direwolf20

I am playing in the Direwolf20 pack on Minecraft version 1.10 from "Feed the Beast," and just returned from the nether. At first I thought my game was bugged because I slept through the night but none of the mobs were dying they were just on fire, they also aggroed at me much more than normal. I also noticed slimes spawning where they shouldn't. After a moment I realized I was under the effect of "Curse."

What is this? Is this causing the mobs to be more hostile than normal and what causes the curse?

You can see the status to the left with the icon:

[image]

Comment: Do you have more than one mod loaded? Multiple mods can conflict and have funky effects.

Comment: @ShawnGordon It's the direwolf20 modpack. the 1.10 version on feed the beast

Comment: ...Unfortunately I don't have an answer at this time. I'll try and search for one to help, however

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `QUARK` mod present on the modpack contains a Soul Bead item.

From the Quark site:

> Wraiths drop a Soul Bead item. Right clicking it will break it, and
>   inflict a Curse debuff on the player for 20 minutes. Mobs in a 64
>   block radius of a player with Curse will spawn ignoring light levels
>   and other conditions (like slime chunk restrictions). Curse can not be
>   cleansed with Milk.

-[QUARK MOD, WORLD TAB](http://quark.vazkii.us/#module-world)